# How to get my active users' information from Android Market?

Tags: android

Not really a programming question but is closely related.  I am trying to send a notification to the users of my app, but for reason I can't see how I can get their emails from my Developer's Console.  Anyone know how I can get that list?  I have a full list of emails in my database for when they signed up within the app, but I only want my active users, and in my database I can't distinguish between active and inactive.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: You won't be able to get their emails. That could cause some serious privacy issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't send you the emails unless they pay for the app (then they do it so you can cancel orders or send refunds).  The way to send an announcement to all users is to use Push messaging.